# Rspec and testing instance methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

Here is my `rspec` file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Classroom, focus: true do

  describe "associations" do
    it { should belong_to(:user) }
  end

  describe "validations" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:user) }
  end

  describe "instance methods" do

    describe "archive!" do
      before(:each) do
        @classroom = build_stubbed(:classroom)
      end

      context "when a classroom is active" do
        it "should mark classroom as inactive" do
          @classroom.archive!
          @classroom.active.should_be == false
        end
      end

    end

  end

end
```

Here is my `Classroom Factory`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :classroom do
    name "Hello World"
    active true

    trait :archive do
      active false
    end
  end

end
```

When the instance method test runs above, I receive the following error: `stubbed models are not allowed to access the database`

I understand why this is happening (but my lack of test knowledge/being a newb to testing) but can't figure out how to stub out the model so that it doesn't hit the database

**Working Rspec Tests:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Classroom, focus: true do

  let(:classroom) { build(:classroom) }

  describe "associations" do
    it { should belong_to(:user) }
  end

  describe "validations" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:user) }
  end

  describe "instance methods" do

    describe "archive!" do

      context "when a classroom is active" do
        it "should mark classroom as inactive" do
          classroom.archive!
          classroom.active == false
        end
      end

    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `archive!` method is trying to save the model to the database. And since you created it as a stubbed model, it doesn't know how to do this.  You have 2 possible solutions for this:

- Change your method to `archive`, don't save it to the database, and call that method in your spec instead.
- Don't use a stubbed model in your test.

Thoughtbot provides a good example of stubbing dependencies [here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/22670085288/use-factory-girls-build-stubbed-for-a-faster-test).  The subject under test (`OrderProcessor`) is a bona fide object, while the items passed through it are stubbed for efficiency.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am completely lost when it comes to writing TDD

Comment: @dennismonsewicz: Updated - see link for example.  In your case, change `build_stubbed` to `build`.  Even better you can make this test less brittle if you make a trait called `active`, and use `build(:classroom, :active)`

Comment: thanks so much for the help! I'm posting what I came up with above